# What does strftime do on call with wrong maxsize parameter?

Tags: c++

I asked myself, what the strftime function does, if I call it with a wrong maxsize argument. Here's the example:

```
char t[19];
struct stat b;
stat(path.c_str(), &b);
strftime(t, 19, "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", localtime(&b.st_mtime));
```

The problem here is that the time format has a length of 19 chars. But strftime() adds a `\0` character to the end of the string. So when I call `strftime` with `maxsize = 19`, what does it do?

1. Simply don't add the `\0` character
2. Ignore the maxsize and write 20 bytes to the char[] t (and thereby risking a buffer overflow)
3. Shorten the output string and add a `\0` character, i.e. "2015-10-12 11-48-1\0"

**Update:**
I am using the VS6 compiler (Win32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strftime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime)

> Return value
>
> The number of bytes written into the character array pointed to by str
>   not including the terminating '\0' on success. **If count was reached
>   before the entire string could be stored, ​0​ is returned and the
>   contents are undefined.**